# Is it possible to change the color of a MaterialDesignIcon?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I use a MaterialDesignIcon in a label like this:

```
Label info = new Label("Label", MaterialDesignIcon.AC_UNIT.graphic("-fx-fill: red;"));
```

I don't know what CSS is supports (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) but I thought it was `Text`. `-fx-underline` worked and so did `-fx-font-size`. I understand that other font properties don't always work because the font doesn't support them, so that's fine. None of the `Shape` properties worked so the above `fill` doesn't do anything.

I only see the colors change by the Swatch but I want something local. What CSS properties are supported and how can I change a single icon's color?

Comment: did you try `-fx-text-fill: red` ?

Comment: @jns didn't before but tried now and that works. So what CSS is supported by that icon? `Labeled`?

Comment: `MaterialDesignIcon.graphic()` creates an instance of `Label`. You can inspect your GUI with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)

Comment: Ah, you're right. Post an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MaterialDesignIcon.graphic()` creates an instance of `Label`. So to change its color you can use `fx-text-fill: red`.

To inspect your GUI you can use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)